# Android permission not granted using Samsung SDK

Tags: android, android-manifest, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear, samsung-knox

I'm trying to run this sample project where Phone is Consumer.

http://developer.samsung.com/sample-app/view.do?v=S000000069nCT030000

Application is working perfectly using my HTC Desire 820 (4.4.4).

However when I run it on Samsung Galaxy S4 (5.0.1) it crashes when running `onCreate()` in `ConsumerService`

Here's my stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.example.helloaccessory.consumer, PID: 29617
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.example.helloaccessory.consumer.ConsumerService: java.lang.SecurityException: com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY permission is required.
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3167)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:177)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1532)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY permission is required.
at com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.SA.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.SAAgent.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.example.helloaccessory.consumer.ConsumerService.onCreate(ConsumerService.java:52)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1532) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

So basically I'm missing a permission and I confirmed this using:

```
String permission = "com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY";
int res = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

Which returned `false`

However, I'm including this permission in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.example.helloaccessory.consumer"
android:versionCode="4"
android:versionName="2.0.2" >

<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.accessory.permission.ACCESSORY_FRAMEWORK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.wmanager.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.WATCH_APP_TYPE.Companion"/>

<application...
```

I'm building using gradle with these versioning:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.example.helloaccessory.consumer"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 4
    versionName '2.0.2'
}
```

Also I'm using

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Phone is not rooted.

Does anybody have any idea why is this happening and how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `<uses-feature android:name="com.sec.feature.spen_usp" android:required="true"/>` to your manifest.

Comment: @ksno still crashing, same error

Comment: Maybe this permission is not granted anymore on 5.0.1

Comment: just checked on Xiaomi Redmi Note 2 (5.0.2) and it works fine.
I also have this issue using Galaxy Note4 (6.0.1). So I guess this is related to Samsung devices. I think KNOX might be blocking this permission but I don't know how to disable it.

Comment: Any news on this? I am having the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Nothing changed, still having issue

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?

Comment: I ran into a very similar issue on some Samsung phones and in my case `shrinkResources true` turned out to be the culprit. It more or less emptied out the "accessory services" xml (in res/xml), which meant my provider service was also missing there. Try turning it off, or add a ['keep' rule](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-resources) for the resource shrinker.

Comment: I have faced Same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to update Samsung Pass SDK to 1.2.2

http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass

I don't know what happened, but 1.2.1 doesn't work more also adding permission in Androidmanifest.